# Select Top Order By query returns unexpected result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a query in SQL Server 2008 like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 SPECIAL_CODE1 * 
  FROM CUSTOMERS 
 WHERE isnumeric(SPECIAL_CODE1)=1 
ORDER BY SPECIAL_CODE1 DESC
```

The query result retuns as `'9970'`. There are rows that have a column value of `'34780'` or `'19850'`.

How can I correct my query?

Comment: If you are storing numbers, why aren't you storing them in a numeric column?

Comment: is `TOP 1 SPECIAL_CODE1 *` correct syntax? Does it need the `*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'9970' is bigger than '34780' if we are talking string values ('9' > '3'). If it's a field defined as integer, then things are of course different. Try something like

```
SELECT TOP 1 SPECIAL_CODE1 * FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE isnumeric(SPECIAL_CODE1)=1 
ORDER BY CAST (SPECIAL_CODE1 AS INTEGER) DESC
```

Comment: You would need `ORDER BY CAST (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SPECIAL_CODE1)=1  THEN SPECIAL_CODE1 END AS INTEGER) DESC` (ignoring issues with `isnumeric` for now). Otherwise the cast can happen before the filter.

Answer (score 1):

The column is being stored as character data, not integers (notice that the it thinks the one that starts with "99" is highest, even if there is a "111"). The solution is either to alter your schema to make that column store integers, or alter your query to cast the column:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY CAST(SPECIAL_CODE1 as int) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you are sorting the results by SPECIAL_CODE1. What is the data type of the field?it looks like it is either varchar or char. You need to convert the data type when you sort. For exampke,
    ORDER BY CAST(SPECIAL_CODE1 AS INT)
This will return the results sorted numerically instead of charater based sorted

Answer (score 1):

The above queries work because the order by is probably going to be evaluated after the filter.  However, it is safer to surround the cast with a case statement:

```
order by (case when isnumeric(special_code1) = 1 then cast(special_code1 as int) end)
```

The case statement is the only statement that guarantees some order of evaluation.  If the cast occurred elsewhere in the query, such as in the SELECT, then the query would probably generate an error the first time it hit a non-numeric value.

SQL is a declarative language, so the query engine can rearrange the components of the query in ways that you might not expect.